# Search for unicode text inside Windows XP

Tags: unicode, windows-xp

Is there a way of searching for unicode characters inside a text file under Windows XP?  For example suppose I wish to find text documents with the euro symbol.  Although the standard XP search allows me to search for the euro symbol it does not produce any matches when I know they should be at least a few. Wingrep has the same issue.  Is there any simple software/setting the I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input encoding of the search field (in Windows XP, UTF-16) may not match the encoding of the text file (probably UTF-8).

I haven't used [this tool](http://www.easexp.com/xsearch/) (freeware), but it might work for your needs.

Comment: I would suggest that this question is better suited for superuser.com however.

Answer (score 0):

In windows or what ever else system you can find out that is it the document unicode (have a unicode character ) or not ?

To achieve this just use this simpl code, not that this code, written in C# and you should use your own equevalent.

```
public bool IsUnicode(string str)
{
 int asciiBytesCount = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(str);
 int unicodBytesCount = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(str);

 if (asciiBytesCount!=unicodBytesCount )
     return true;

 return false;
}
```

if you do not want to write any code and find out that , is document contain any unicode character just see the document (save) Type.